# Now i am getting a error with relationed entities attributes with the resultTransformer

Tags: hibernate

Suppose this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(TramiteTrafico.class);
criteria.createAlias("contrato","contrato");
criteria.createAlias("contrato.provincia","provincia");
```

where tramiteTrafico is relationed with contrato and it does have setter for contrato object into TramiteTrafico entity.

I am trying to do this:

```
proList.add(Projections.property("provincia.nombre"),"contrato.provincia.nombre");
```

And i get this error: Could not find setter for contrato.provincia.nombre on class estadisticas.beans.entities.TramiteTrafico

How can I fix it for relationed attributes of the entity?

Comment: Can you please post your `TransmiteTrafico` class code, more precisely the getter and setter for `Provincia` ?

Comment: public class TramiteTrafico implements Serializable {
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ID_CONTRATO")
private Contrato contrato;

 public Contrato getContrato() {
  return this.contrato;
 }

 public void setContrato(Contrato contrato) {
  this.contrato = contrato;
 }
}

Comment: public class Contrato implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name="ID_PROVINCIA")
 private Provincia provincia;

 public Provincia getProvincia() {
  return this.provincia;
 }

 public void setProvincia(Provincia provincia) {
  this.provincia = provincia;
 }
}

Comment: sorry, I cant do it well to understand code :s

Comment: Now that I understand your mapping, what are you trying to achieve with `proList.add(Projections.property("provincia.nombre"),"contrato.provincia.nombre");` ? What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 0):

my guess is you use transformers.aliastobean to project into the model class. However AliasToBean can not set cascading properties like `address.street` because it does not know how to create an address object in the first place and assumes there is a property with the name `address.street` on the root class.

to remedy that use a flattened Dto to project into or just load the complete TramiteTrafico objects (don't set projections and transformer).